# Adding Onclick attribute to wpforms button tag

Tags: html, wordpress, onclick

I need to insert an onclick attribute inside the submit button tag. May I know how to insert it? im using wordpress.org & a plugin called wpforms.

http://i63.tinypic.com/103evd0.jpg

This is the code that I need to insert

```
onclick="return gtag_report_conversion(‘http://example.com/your-link')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if WPForms allows changes through hook filters, since I couldn't find in their docs, but you can do this with attaching event via jQuery using '#wpforms-submit-2113' id as selector, or '.wpforms-submit' for more general rule.

```
jQuery('#wpforms-submit-2113').click(function(){
gtag_report_conversion('http://example.com/your-link');
});
```

Comment: Tq im gonna try this.. but may I know at what file and which file directory i need to put this code on?

Comment: if you have a theme, or custom plugin, add in file for custom javascript code there. Or add new js file by using wp_enqueue_script within 'init' hook function.

Comment: i tried adding it using Simple Custom CSS and JS and the result still the same.. Guess the code not works.. Got any other solution?